# Amazon Device Farm with Calabash says devices are all unavailable

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, calabash-android

I'm trying to run calabash tests for my app on `Amazon Device Farm`, but a very simple check for text test always yields the following error, acrross all possible devices (yes, I tried all of them):

```
This device was unavailable and skipped
```

No other information is provided.

I made a simple app that just shows some static text and a test that checks for it, and it runs fine. But if I strip all permissions from my app, no internet, nothing required, same test, it gives this message.

How come there are no devices for my app, but there are identical devices for the sample app? How can I find out what specific feature I'm using that is not available?

This is what I see:

[image: error]

Answer (score 3):

I am from the AWS Device Farm team.

One possible failure point is using special characters (character whose encoding are different in UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1) in the suite and test name in your test package.

This is currently broken and a fix is in the works and will be released soon.

Can you verify that you are not using special characters in your test package in the suite and test name? If you are you will need to change this.

Comment: That was it, Anurag! Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @LuanNico Download Sample app from [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-device-farm-calabash-tests-for-sample-app) and run it in DeviceFarm. It that app succeeded, the issue is in your app, else it is devicefarm issue.